# How do I prevent default implementation of exponential operator (^)

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and I am getting an error when compiling the following code

```hs
(^) :: Int -> Int -> Int
_ ^ 0 = 1
x ^ n = x * (x ^ (n-1))
```

The error is this:

```
Ambiguous occurrence `^'
It could refer to
either `Prelude.^',
imported from `Prelude' at test.lhs:1:1
(and originally defined in `GHC.Real')
or `Main.^', defined at test.lhs:107:5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short, [`Prelude` has that function already](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-) and you are redefining it, so the compiler doesn't know which one to pick.

If you put

```hs
import Prelude hiding ((^))
```

on the top of your file, you'll resolve the ambiguity in favour of your definition by hiding the other one from the `Prelude`.